# Simplification of factorials

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, factorial

Just had a quick question about the simplification of the following factorial.

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n}$$

why does this simplify this way?

Comment: Look at $4!/5! = (4 \times 3 \times 2)/(5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2)$ and generalize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$ Because $n! := n(n-1)!$ ([recursive definition of factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Definition))

---

Intuitively, you can think of this:

$$\dfrac{(n-1)!}{n!} = \dfrac{\cancel{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (n-1)}}{\cancel{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (n-1)} \cdot n} = \dfrac 1 n$$

Comment: thanks for those edits, the answer is very clear and helpful!

Comment: I keep forgetting how to do strikethrough with MathJax.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$This comes from the definition of a factorial.

Perhaps it is easier to see an example with a number.

Let $n=5$. Then we have:

$$\dfrac{(5-1)!}{5!}=\dfrac{4!}{5!}=\dfrac{4\times 3\times 2\times 1}{5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1}=
\dfrac{\cancel{4\times 3\times 2\times 1}}{5\times \cancel{4\times 3\times 2\times 1}}=\dfrac{1}{5}=\dfrac{1}{n}$$

Comment: You need to do `\require{cancel}` somewhere

Comment: Require? I don't know that keyword ... whats wrong with the current cancel?

Comment: nothing is wrong with your syntax. But the cancel module isn't loaded until you require it.

Comment: Can you edit it for me? I'm not sure I know what you mean

Comment: I don't really see the difference?